# How can we send a data from our JS file to kafka without using socket.io

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm getting a JSON data from a file into my javascript file. Now I want to send that data from that javascript file to kafka server hence kafka producer without using socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get JSON data into Kafka from a file, then use Kafka Connect and the `spooldir` connector. You can see an example [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/).

If you want to send data from a JS application to Kafka then you could use the [Confluent REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#kafkarest-intro) or a client such as [this one](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka).